# How to filter category when i load from Mage_Catalog_Model_Category?

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, model, collection-filtering

I have the code bellow and i want exclude a category id 70 from collection, but i tried with :

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin'=>'70'));
```

and doesn't works

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
   $category->load();
 $_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
        $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',4)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        // $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin'=>'70'));
        $_productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
        $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
        $_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

Comment: why you do not use category id in load()function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `addCategoryIds()` method, to enable filtering of category ids, so like this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoryIds()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(array('nin'=>'70')))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);

$productCollection->getSelect()
    ->order('RAND()')
    ->limit(20);

$productCollection->load();
```